# Laptop standby on Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, standby

One of the reasons I'm not currently on Ubuntu is that standby doesn't work well. It does one of the fallowing:

- doesn't go to standby
- crashes on standby
- crashes on resume from standby

This happened on Ubuntu 7.04, 8.04 and 8.10. I haven't tried 9.04 yet. I'm on a Dell Inspiron 17xx.

The question is:

**On what Linux distribution, that you use frequently for desktop applications, didn't you problems with standby?**

Comment: +1 - I have a similar problem on Fedora 10 on my Dell Inspiron 1700 (random crash on resume from standby)

Comment: The real question is not on what system _I_ had no problem with standby... the problem is far too hardware-specific for that to get you a useful answer.

The question is, what hardware in your machine is preventing standby, and how to work around that? What GPU, what networking chip? 

Note that on those machines where standby/resume worked for me, it also worked directly running the Live CD. So you might figure this out without installing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give Ubuntu 9.04 a try, that is the first Ubuntu distro I have had that I didn't have to fuss over Standby or Hibernate.

Comment: ditto, 9.04 really made a difference for me in this respect!

Comment: I'll do this, I have some installing to do :)

Answer (score 1):

I have a Dell Vostro 1500, and the Standby / Hibernate support in Ubuntu 9.04 has been nothing short of **fantastic**. Compared to Windows XP and 7, it's light years faster - of course, your mileage may vary, but compared to 8.10 it's been a dream.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Ubuntu since it first came out on a few laptops.

- IBM Thinkpad T41
- IBM Thinkpad T42
- Dell Inspiron 1701 (I think, 17" monstrosity)
- Dell Latitude D820
- Dell Inspiron 1526

I had suspend/resume problems with the Thinkpad T41 and the Latitude D820 across multiple versions. The Inspiron 1526 with versions 7.10 through 9.04 have worked great with suspend/resume.

Answer (score 1):

I have Dell Vostro 1400 (the old one). Standby and hibernate looks like works fine with 9.04. I have some problems with earlier Ubuntu versions: after few hibernates laptop doesn't boot up to OS. These standby and hibernate problems depends on your hardware. And here can't be direct answer witch distribution you should choose, because it depends on your laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu works fine on my laptop with standby.

It sounds like this problem has something to do with the gnome power manager so my best bet is to either install some other power manager (if that's possible) or try to use KDE as window manager instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am on a Dell D830 and hibernate works about 80% of the time. I am running 9.04.

I've had it crash both when going into and out of hibernate. I don't use the suspend feature, so I cannot speak to that.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes used to have trouble with standby if I closed the lid. However, it would work perfectly if I initiated standby from the shutdown/logoff/etc. menu instead. You could try that if you continue to have problems.

Answer (score 0):

I use Debian (testing + some unstable, so roughly equivalent to current Ubuntu) on a IBM Thinkpad T41. Both suspend-to-disk and suspend-to-RAM have worked flawlessly out of the box.